# How to automatically share file with a specific email address / user?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am using Google API Client to upload and convert a file to that user's google drive.  How can I automatically share that file with one specific user?

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->title = $title;
  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

  // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
  $client->setDefer(true);
  $request = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'convert' => true,
));
```

The webapp is an HTML form that creates a document based on user data. This document needs to later be edited by myself, saved in my google drive, and deleted from the user's google drive.

What is the best/easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To share a file with the Drive API you use `Permissions.insert()` with the type "user", role of either "reader", "writer", or "commenter", and a value which is their email address. More information about sharing files is available in [this developer guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing).